# How to wait for data to be populated in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-context, use-context

I am having a strange problem where petData is initially being logged to the console as undefined and a few moments later populating the array of data. I assume this has to do with the time it takes to fetch the data and then send it through context. The problem is the app is crashing with the error "TypeError: can't access property "name", petData[0] is undefined" I tried using setTimeout but that does not help. Are there any solutions to this?

```
function SearchPage() {
  const { petData } = useContext(PetDataContext);
  console.log(petData[0].name);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
    if (filter == "") return petData;
    return petData.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
        item.breed.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
    );
  }, [petData, filter]);

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar onSearch={(searchTerm) => setFilter(searchTerm)} />
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap sp-body">
        <DogCardsDisplayed petData={filteredData} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [petData, setPetData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data`)
      .then(function (response) {
        setPetData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire("Oops...", error.response.data, "error");
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(petData);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PetDataContext.Provider value={{ petData }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={MainSignedOut} exact />
            <Route path="/mainsignedin" component={MainSignedIn} />
            <Route path="/searchpage" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/mypets" component={MyPets} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route exact path="/pets/:id" component={PetPage} />
            <Route component={err404} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PetDataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Context.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const PetDataContext = createContext([]);
export default PetDataContext;
```

Comment: How certain are you that you need the context API for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are trying to access and log `petData[0].name` before `petData` contains any data.  You want to write your component to not attempt to access data that doesn't exist, and probably rewrite it to handle that case and render some sort of fallback UI until it has data to render.

Comment: so is it best not to use context?

Comment: The React documentation dissuades from its use unless necessary, as it adds complexity and some performance considerations.  See ["Before You Use Context" from the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function App() {
  const [petData, setPetData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data`)
      .then(function (response) {
        setPetData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire("Oops...", error.response.data, "error");
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(petData);
  return petData ? (
    <div className="App">
      <PetDataContext.Provider value={{ petData }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={MainSignedOut} exact />
            <Route path="/mainsignedin" component={MainSignedIn} />
            <Route path="/searchpage" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/mypets" component={MyPets} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route exact path="/pets/:id" component={PetPage} />
            <Route component={err404} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PetDataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  ) : (
    "Loading pets..."
  );
}
```

### How it works

The idea here is that since network calls are synchronous (they run concurrently and you can't tell when they execute), you simply watch the `petData` state that would be updated and show the actual content when the `petData` state holds a valid value. Until then, you can show some basic loader, like the kind you see on sites, maybe a spinner or something.

Comment: This works if you change the initial state to null instead of [ ]. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, you could also do `return petData.length ? (<PetDataContext />) : "Loading"` if you must initialize the state to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution. Modify your `App.js` file. I think you are hitting a race condition, You will have to install `react-async-hook`

```
import { useAsync } from 'react-async-hook';

function App() {

  fetchPetData = () => {
      return  axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data`)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire("Oops...", error.response.data, "error");
      });
  }

  const value = useAsync(fetchPetData);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PetDataContext.Provider value={{ value }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={MainSignedOut} exact />
            <Route path="/mainsignedin" component={MainSignedIn} />
            <Route path="/searchpage" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/mypets" component={MyPets} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route exact path="/pets/:id" component={PetPage} />
            <Route component={err404} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PetDataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```